# Why does android studio kept telling me I havent made a project table in my database even though I made one?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I made two table one for user and one for project but project is not being made for some reason

```
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Users";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "Username";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "Password";
//    Column and table for new project
    private static final String PROJECT_TABLE = "Project";
    private static final String COLUMN_id = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME = "projectName";
    private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String COLUMN_TEAM = "team";
    private static final String COLUMN_PROJECT_MANAGER = "Project_Manager";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                "(" + COLUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT);";

        String project = "CREATE TABLE " + PROJECT_TABLE +
                "(" + COLUMN_id +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_TEAM + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_PROJECT_MANAGER + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(project);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PROJECT_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    void addProject(String projectName, String Description, String team, String projectManager){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME, projectName);
        cv.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, Description);
        cv.put(COLUMN_TEAM, team);
        cv.put(COLUMN_PROJECT_MANAGER, projectManager);
        long result = db.insert(PROJECT_TABLE, null ,cv);
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to add new project", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added new project", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

in my project java class I thought that maybe the data is not properly being inserted to the database so what I did was in the db.addProject I coded it to get the strings and text but it still didnt work

```
public class Board extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText projectName, description, team, projectManager;
    Button done;
    userDB db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_board);
        projectName = findViewById(R.id.projectName);
        description = findViewById(R.id.description);
        team = findViewById(R.id.team);
        projectManager = findViewById(R.id.projectManager);
        done = findViewById(R.id.button);

        done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String projectname = projectName.getText().toString().trim();
                String desc = description.getText().toString().trim();
                String Team = team.getText().toString().trim();
                String projectmanage = projectManager.getText().toString().trim();

                if(projectname.equals("") || desc.equals("") || Team.equals("") ||
                projectmanage.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(Board.this, "All Fields are Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    db = new userDB(Board.this);
                    db.addProject(projectName.getText().toString().trim(),
                            description.getText().toString().trim(),
                            team.getText().toString().trim(),
                            projectManager.getText().toString().trim());
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Board.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

I have tried retconning some syntaxes but it all ends up in the same error. I have been stuck with this same error for 3 hrs and I dont know what to do anymore ;-;

Answer (score 0):

One mistake is, in the method addProject(), you are opening the database in the Read mode (getReadableDatabase()). It has to be in the Write mode getWritableDatabase() for inserting data into table. Also, after you insert the data, make it a point to close it by calling the close() method.

I tried running this code snippet with the changes I suggested, on my laptop and its working very fine. Its creating the database with 2 tables Users and Project. Also, its inserting the data into the Project table.  I have attached the image of the output (database inspector) where you can clearly see the 2 tables and the new record inserted into Project table. You can check it out.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText projectName, description, team, projectManager;
Button done;
userDB db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    projectName = findViewById(R.id.projectName);
    description = findViewById(R.id.description);
    team = findViewById(R.id.team);
    projectManager = findViewById(R.id.projectManager);
    done = findViewById(R.id.button);

    done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String projectname = projectName.getText().toString().trim();
            String desc = description.getText().toString().trim();
            String Team = team.getText().toString().trim();
            String projectmanage = projectManager.getText().toString().trim();

            if(projectname.equals("") || desc.equals("") || Team.equals("") ||
                    projectmanage.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "All Fields are Required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                db = new userDB(MainActivity.this);
                db.addProject(projectName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        description.getText().toString().trim(),
                        team.getText().toString().trim(),
                        projectManager.getText().toString().trim());

                db.queryDB();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Here is the userDB class

```
public class userDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Users";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "Username";
private static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "Password";
//    Column and table for new project
private static final String PROJECT_TABLE = "Project";
private static final String COLUMN_id = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME = "projectName";
private static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";
private static final String COLUMN_TEAM = "team";
private static final String COLUMN_PROJECT_MANAGER = "Project_Manager";

private Context context ;
public userDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query =  "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
            "(" + COLUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT);";

    String project = "CREATE TABLE " + PROJECT_TABLE +
            "(" + COLUMN_id +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_TEAM + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_PROJECT_MANAGER + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(project);
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PROJECT_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

}

public void addProject(String projectName, String Description, String team, String projectManager){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_PROJECT_NAME, projectName);
    cv.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, Description);
    cv.put(COLUMN_TEAM, team);
    cv.put(COLUMN_PROJECT_MANAGER, projectManager);
    long result = db.insert(PROJECT_TABLE, null ,cv);
    if(result == -1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to add new project", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully added new project", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    db.close();
}

public void queryDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++){
                //TODO: replace numbers with column count constants
                Toast.makeText(context, cursor.getString(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    db.close();
}
```

}

And the output (Database inspector) is here:
[image]

Comment: I have already tried that last night but I am still getting the same error

Comment: I have edited my answer with the changes I had suggested. Please check the answer again. It has the output also. It should work for you also.

Comment: Thank you it appears that all I needed to do was to uninstall and install the app from the emulator to make it work XDD I appreciate the help very much ^ ^